# Threads creating process in infinite loop

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt, ffmpeg

In my application a thread runs while(1){} in it so thread terminates when my app is terminated by user.

Is it safe to do like this? I am using while(1){} because my app continuously monitors devices on system.

After some time I am getting "(R6016) not enough space for thread data" on ffmpeg.

I read this but did not get solution of my problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126709

Thread description:
Thread uses ffmpeg and handle utility (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). within while(1){} loop.

ffmpeg and handle is running through QProcess which I am deleting after process ends.

while(1){} loop waits for 5 seconds using
    msleep(5000).

Comment: The error message suggests that you are allocating memory within the while(1) and not freeing it or re-using it.

Comment: I am deleting all objects created with new but still this happen I am getting it why

Comment: We can't possibly answer this without seeing the code.

Comment: The error message relates to TLS so something is wrong that we cannot deduce from the information you have supplied. As Harry quite rightly says, we need to see the code to help you.

Answer (score 3):

This is not safe.

Change `while (1)` to `while (!stopCondition)` and have stopCondition change to TRUE when exiting. The main thread should wait for all other thread to finish before exiting.

Note: `stopCondition` is defined as `volatile int stopCondition`.

When the main thread exists, a cleanup process starts:
 - global destructors are called (C++).
 - C runtime library starts to shut down, releasing all memory allocated with `malloc`, unloading dynamic libraries and other resources.

A thread that depends on the C runtime being functional will crash or if it runs code from a shared/dynamic libray. If that thread was doing something important like writing to a file, the file will be corrupt. Maybe in your case things are not so bad, but seeing an application crash doesn't looks good to say the least.

This is not the full story, but I think it makes my point.

Comment: but I am continously monitering devices so i need while(1) and once my thread started only user has the right to close it just by closing application.

Comment: If the worker thread is doing something while the main thread exists, you can get a crash, maybe some files will be corrupt, etc.

Comment: can u pls explain this

Comment: added some background.

Comment: This doesn't sound like the OPs problem, which happens *before* the process attempts to exit.  Also, typically the preferred solution is to call `ExitProcess` rather than letting the runtime library wind everything down (though admittedly this depends on how extensively and in what ways the runtime library is used).  If `ExitProcess` is used there shouldn't be any problems - provided of course the thread's code is written to allow for the fact that it will be terminated without warning.